# Error in SQL Server 2005 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 

GO 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Prc_InsertUpdate] (@boxone   VARCHAR(200), 
                                          @boxtwo   VARCHAR(200), 
                                          @boxthree VARCHAR(200)) 
AS 
  DECLARE @num AS INT 

  SELECT @num = MAX(NUMBER) + 1 
  FROM   updatepage 

  INSERT INTO [TestDB].[dbo].[updatepage] 
              ([number], 
               [box1], 
               [box2], 
               [box3]) 
  VALUES      (@num, 
               @boxone, 
               @boxtwo, 
               @boxthree)
```

I'm creating this procedure but got this error

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure Prc_InsertUpdate, Line 9
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.Prc_InsertUpdate'.

Comment: Oh, that `SELECT MAX(Number)+1` is *truly* horrific. Even if you wrapped it's selection and subsequent use in a serializable transaction, it would still be bad.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I would +1 gazillion you if I could .....

Answer (score 2):

You are `ALTER`-ing a stored procedure that does not exist. Use `CREATE procedure [dbo].[Prc_InsertUpdate]` instead.

Also why isn't `number` an `identity` column? Your current approach is inefficient and not safe under conditions of concurrency?

Comment: @AlexK. - True but the text of the question says they are "creating this procedure"